# Magento 2 customer is always redirected back to /checkout/cart/

Tags: magento2, checkout, redirect

We have some customers gettign in touch stating that whenever they go to [www.domain.com/checkout](http://www.domain.com/checkout) they are just redirected back to [www.domain.com/checkout/cart](http://www.domain.com/checkout/cart) page.

Has anyone else had this issue before?

I have checked the system logs and see the following errors:

```
main.WARNING: Broken reference: The element with the "customer_account_navigation" ID wasn't found. Verify the ID and try again. [] []
main.CRITICAL: The following tag(s) are not allowed: img [] []
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hey, if I understood it right that problem does not happens with all users, so I would start to try to understand what's the requirement to that to happen, for example if it only happens to logged in users, if yes, if it's just to user with a specific group; if it is caused by some product in the cart or some cart rule; maybe check if the account of the users that has the issue is missing some value (for example we had an error once because some accounts didn't had a value that was required); might find something to start with

Comment: @RuiSilva Thank you very much. Your thinking is correct. I will investigate customer/product/cart rules with more detail. Appreciate it

Comment: It can be a lot of thing, do that to at least have an idea of what it is, with that we can be more specific in our search for the real cause, let us know if you find something

Comment: does the customers has a quote? If the customers doesn't have one or more products in the cart, and try to visit the checkout page, the result is a redirect on the checkout/cart